A probability inequality used Chernoff bounds.
$X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ are independent random variables with $P(X_k =1)=2^{-k}$,$P(X_k =0)=1-2^{-k} $, for $k\ge 1$.
Let $S_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}X_i$. Use Chernoff bounds to show that
$$
P(\mathop{\sup}\limits_{n}S_n>1+\delta)\le \frac{e^\delta}{(1+\delta)^{1+\delta}}, \quad \text{for any} \quad \delta>0.
$$
I have met only one problem that how to approximate $\mathop{\min}\limits_{t>0} \{e^{-(1+\delta)}\prod_{k=1}^{n}[(1-2^{-k})+2^{-k}e^t]\} $ to the conclusion.
Thanks in advance if you can answer my question.
Chernoff bounds are $P(X\ge a)\le \mathop{\min}\limits_{t>0} \{e^{-ta}M(t) \} $ , $M(t)$ is the MGF of $X$.

I have looked but I do not see a question mark in the current set of words. It appears the problem, or question and setup, is incomplete.

Possible hint: Let $X$ be the sum of the $X_i$. What is the mean of $X$? Use the usual Chernoff bound and some estimates. See also Probability and Computing, Mitzenmacher and Upfal.

@Leucippus Thanks for your advice.

@SeanRoberson Thank you very much! This book answers my question and gives me an inspiration!

Get inspiration from the book Probability and Computing, Mitzenmacher and Upfal in page approximately 70
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(\sup\limits_n S_n > 1+\delta) &\le \lim_{n\to \infty} \min\left\{ e^{-t(1+\delta)}E[e^{tX}] \right\} \\
& =  \min\left\{ e^{-t(1+\delta)}\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}[(1-2^{-k})+2^{-k}e^t]
 \right\} \\
& \overset{t=\ln(1+\delta)}{\le} \frac{\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}[(1-2^{-k})+2^{-k}(1+\delta)]}{(1+\delta)^{1+\delta}} \\
& \le \frac{e^\delta}{(1+\delta)^{1+\delta}}
\end{aligned}
$$

Remark, make common math operators look nice with a backslash, e.g., \sup makes $\sup$.

Let
$$
S_{\infty} \;=\;\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}X_k.
$$
Since $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb P(X_k=1)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k}=1$, the Borel–Cantelli lemmas imply $S_{\infty}$ is almost surely finite, and thus $\sup_{n}S_n = S_{\infty}$ almost surely. Therefore
$$
\mathbb P\Bigl(\sup_{n} S_n > 1+\delta\Bigr)
\;=\;
\mathbb P\bigl(S_{\infty} > 1+\delta\bigr).
$$
Fix any $t>0$. Define
$$
W(\omega)
\;=\;
\exp\Bigl(t\,S_{\infty}(\omega)\Bigr)
\;\Big/\;
\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}
\bigl[(1-2^{-k}) \,+\,2^{-k}e^t\bigr].
$$
We can verify that
$$
\mathbb E\bigl[\,W\,\bigr]
\;=\;
\dfrac{1}{\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}[(1-2^{-k})+2^{-k}e^t]}
\;\mathbb E\Bigl[\exp\bigl(t\,S_{\infty}\bigr)\Bigr]
\;=\;
1,
$$
because $\exp\bigl(t\,S_{\infty}\bigr) = \prod_{k=1}^\infty \exp\bigl(t\,X_k\bigr)$ and $\mathbb E\bigl[\exp(t\,X_k)\bigr] = (1-2^{-k}) + 2^{-k} e^t$. Thus $\mathbb E[W]=1$.
Next, observe that
$$
\mathbf{1}\bigl\{S_{\infty} > 1+\delta\bigr\}
\;\;\le\;\;
W\exp\Bigl(-\,t\,(1+\delta)\Bigr)\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1-2^{-k}+2^{-k}e^t)}.
$$
For any particular outcome $\omega$ with $S_{\infty}(\omega) = s$, we have
$$
\mathbf{1}\{s > 1+\delta\}
\;\le\;
\exp\bigl(t\,s - t(1+\delta)\bigr)
\;=\;
\exp\bigl(t\,S_{\infty}(\omega)\bigr)\exp\bigl(-\,t(1+\delta)\bigr).
$$
Multiplying both sides by
$\bigl[\prod_{k=1}^\infty ((1-2^{-k}) + 2^{-k}e^t)\bigr]^{-1}$
gives the desired pointwise inequality for each $\omega$. Taking expectations,
$$
\mathbb P\bigl(S_{\infty} > 1+\delta\bigr)
\;\le\;
\exp\bigl(-\,t\,(1+\delta)\bigr)
\;\dfrac{\mathbb E\bigl[\exp\bigl(t\,S_{\infty}\bigr)\bigr]}
{\prod_{k=1}^\infty\bigl[(1-2^{-k}) + 2^{-k}e^t\bigr]}
\;=\;
\exp\bigl(-\,t\,(1+\delta)\bigr),
$$
where the last equality is simply $\mathbb E[W]=1$.
So we arrive at
$$
\mathbb P\bigl(S_{\infty}>1+\delta\bigr)
\;\le\;
\exp\Bigl(-\,t\,(1+\delta)\Bigr)
\quad
\text{for every real }t>0.
$$
To tighten this, replace each factor $(1-2^{-k}) + 2^{-k} e^t$ by something larger (which only makes the denominator smaller and the resulting bound bigger), namely
$$
(1-2^{-k}) + 2^{-k}\,e^t
\;=\;
1 \;+\; 2^{-k}\,\bigl(e^t - 1\bigr)
\;\le\;
\exp\Bigl\{\,2^{-k}\,\bigl(e^t - 1\bigr)\Bigr\},
$$
so
$$
\prod_{k=1}^\infty
\bigl[(1-2^{-k}) + 2^{-k}e^t\bigr]
\;\le\;
\exp\Bigl\{\,\bigl(e^t - 1\bigr)\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k}\Bigr\}
\;=\;
\exp\bigl(e^t -1\bigr).
$$
Hence
$$
\bigl[\prod_{k=1}^\infty [(1-2^{-k}) + 2^{-k} e^t]\bigr]^{-1}
\;\ge\;
\exp\bigl(-\,\bigl(e^t - 1\bigr)\bigr).
$$
Putting this into the exact expression for $\mathbb E[W]$ in place of the product in the denominator, we see
$$
\mathbb P\bigl(S_{\infty} > 1+\delta\bigr)
\;\le\;
\exp\Bigl(-\,t\,(1+\delta)\Bigr)\exp\bigl(e^t - 1\bigr)
\;=\;
\exp\Bigl(e^t \;-\;1 \;-\; t\,(1+\delta)\Bigr).
$$
Call the exponent
$$
f(t)
\;=\;
e^t - 1 - (1+\delta)\,t.
$$
A quick derivative check shows $f'(t)= e^t - (1+\delta)$ vanishes exactly at $t=\ln(1+\delta)$, and this critical point is a global minimum for $f$. Substituting $t=\ln(1+\delta)$ in $f$ yields
$$
f\bigl(\ln(1+\delta)\bigr)
\;=\;
(1+\delta) - 1 - (1+\delta)\ln(1+\delta)
\;=\;
\delta - (1+\delta)\ln(1+\delta).
$$
Hence
$$
\exp\bigl(f(\ln(1+\delta))\bigr)
\;=\;
\exp\Bigl(\delta - (1+\delta)\ln(1+\delta)\Bigr)
\;=\;
\dfrac{e^{\delta}}{\bigl(1+\delta\bigr)^{1+\delta}}.
$$
Therefore
$$
\mathbb P\bigl(S_{\infty} > 1+\delta\bigr)
\;\le\;
\dfrac{e^\delta}{\bigl(1+\delta\bigr)^{1+\delta}},
$$
which completes the argument. Since $S_{\infty} = \sup_n S_n$ almost surely, the same bound applies to $\mathbb P(\sup_n S_n > 1+\delta)$. Thus we obtain
$$
\mathbb P\Bigl(\sup_n S_n > 1+\delta\Bigr)
\;\le\;
\frac{e^\delta}{(1+\delta)^{1+\delta}}.
$$

Quite the involved argument here.

I’m a 95 year old mathematician what can I say. Have. 1 year left according to doctors.

@RaynardBond Have a good day.  Enjoy solving math problems here.

@RaynardBond Enjoy math, my friend, thanks for your good and helpful answer.
